# Curvature of $r(t)=\langle t,\ln\cos t\rangle$ in Mathematica

Tags: vector-analysis

First, we find the unit tangent vector $T=\frac{r'(t)}{|r'(t)|}$:
$$r'(t)=\left\langle 1,-\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\right\rangle$$
$$|r'(t)|=\sqrt{1+\frac{\sin^2t}{\cos^2t}}=\frac{1}{\cos t}$$
$$T=\frac{r'}{|r'|}=\cos t\left\langle 1,-\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\right\rangle=
\langle \cos t,-\sin t\rangle$$

Next, we find the curvature $\kappa(t)=\frac{|T'(t)|}{|r'(t)|}$:

$$T'(t)=\langle -\sin t,-\cos t\rangle$$
$$|T'(t)|=\sqrt{\sin^2t+\cos^2t}=1$$
$$\kappa(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos t}}=\cos t$$

However, when I tried to check in Mathematica, I got the following output:

> ArcCurvature[{t, Log[Cos[t]]}, t]
> $$\frac{| \sec (t)| ^2}{\left(\tan ^2(t)+1\right)^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with mod signs. Their correct answer simplifies to $\sec^2t/|\sec^3t|=|\cos t|$. You should have said $|r^\prime|=|\sec t|$.